# Improving PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

I just finished writing my first PLSQL function. Here what it does.

The SQL function attempt to reset the duplicate timestamp to NULL.

1. From table call_records find all timestamp that are duplicated.(using group by)
2. loop through each timestamp.Find all record with same timestamp (times-1, so that only 1 record for a given times is present)
3. From all the records found in step 2 update the timestamp to NULL

Here how the SQL function looks like.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nullify() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
T call_records.timestamp%TYPE;
-- Not sure why row_type does not work
-- R call_records%ROWTYPE;
S integer;
CRNS bigint[];
TMPS bigint[];
sql_stmt varchar = '';
BEGIN
FOR T,S IN (select timestamp,count(timestamp) as times from call_records where timestamp IS NOT NULL group by timestamp having count(timestamp) > 1)
LOOP
  sql_stmt := format('SELECT ARRAY(select plain_crn from call_records where timestamp=%s limit %s)',T,S-1);
  EXECUTE sql_stmt INTO TMPS;
  CRNS := array_cat(CRNS,TMPS);
END LOOP;

  sql_stmt = format('update call_records set timestamp=null where plain_crn in (%s)',array_to_string(CRNS,','));
  RAISE NOTICE '%',sql_stmt;
  EXECUTE sql_stmt ;
  RETURN 1;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Help me understand more PL/pgSQL language my suggesting me how it can be done better.

@a_horse_with_no_name: Here how the DB structure looks like
\d+ call_records;

```
id  integer primary key
plain_crn  bigint
timestamp  bigint
efd        integer default 0




    id    |    efd     | plain_crn  | timestamp 
----------+------------+------------+-----------
    1     | 2016062936 | 8777444059 | 14688250050095        
    2     | 2016062940 | 8777444080 | 14688250050095
    3     | 2016063012 | 8880000000 | 14688250050020      
    4     | 2016043011 | 8000000000 | 14688240012012
    5     | 2016013011 | 8000000001 | 14688250050020 
    6     | 2016022011 | 8440000001 |
```

Now,

```
select timestamp,count(timestamp) as times from call_records where timestamp IS NOT NULL group by timestamp having count(timestamp) > 1 

  timestamp      |    count 
-----------------+-----------
 14688250050095  |      2
 14688250050020  |      2
```

All that I want is to update the duplicate timestamp to null so that only one of them record has the given timestamp.

In short the above query should return result like this

```
   select timestamp,count(timestamp) as times from call_records where timestamp IS NOT NULL group by timestamp;

      timestamp      |    count 
    -----------------+-----------
     14688250050095  |      1
     14688250050020  |      1
```

Comment: There is no need for dynamic SQL here. I don't think you need a function at all, this sounds as if this could be done using a single update statement. But without the complete table definition and some sample data this is nearly impossible to tell

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array variables directly (filter with predicate `=ANY()` - using dynamic SQL is wrong for this purpose:

```
postgres=# DO $$
DECLARE x int[] = '{1,2,3}'; 
result int[];
BEGIN
  SELECT array_agg(v) 
    FROM generate_series(1,10) g(v) 
   WHERE v = ANY(x)
    INTO result;
  RAISE NOTICE 'result is: %', result;
END;
$$;
NOTICE:  result is: {1,2,3}
DO
```

Next - this is typical void function - it doesn't return any interesting. Usually these functions returns nothing when all is ok or raises exception. The returning 1 `RETURN 1` is useless.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(par int)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM footab WHERE id = par)
  THEN 
    ...
  ELSE
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Missing data for parameter: %', par;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Which array variable are you taking about over here?

Comment: x is the array variable